# Why is AdS spacetime like a "saddle"?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature, cosmological-constant, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

When the shape of the universe is discussed, the three cases are flat, closed and open. Where AdS spacetime with a negative cosmological constant describes the open spacetime, as in the middle in the below figure.  [image]

When reading about AdS spacetime, for example Eq. (2.1) [here](https://sites.krieger.jhu.edu/jared-kaplan/files/2016/05/AdSCFTCourseNotesCurrentPublic.pdf), the metric in global coordinates read

$$ds^2 = \frac{1}{\cos^2(\rho /R)}\Big( dt^2 - d\rho^2 - \sin^2(\rho /R) d\Omega_{d-1}^2  \Big).$$ One can visualize this coordinate system as a cylinder as in the below figure.

[image]

Now, if no one told me this is supposed to represent an "open" universe shaped like a "saddle" I would not have noticed. I understand that there's a singularity at $\rho = \pi /2$ if we put $R$ to unity, but how would I be able to just from the above metric know that this would represent an open "saddle" universe? Would I have to do a coordinate transformation? Because I am not sure where the Poincaré disk would lie at this saddle. I struggle to see how the picture of a cylinder and the picture of half a hyperboloid is somehow equivalent?